# Pancake glutton program. (C++)

Tags: c++

Requires:
variables, data types, and numerical operators
basic input/output
logic (if statements, switch statements)
loops (for, while, do-while)
arrays

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

★ Modify the program so that it also outputs which person ate the least number of pancakes for breakfast.

★★★★ Modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.
i.e.
Person 4: ate 10 pancakes
Person 3: ate 7 pancakes
Person 8: ate 4 pancakes
...
Person 5: ate 0 pancakes

Current version I have written: http://codepad.org/QHnt11CT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) {
      bool swapped = true;
      int j = 0;
      int tmp;
      while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) {
                  if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                        tmp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                        arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                        swapped = true;
                  }
            }
      }
}

int main()
{
    int pancakeAmount[10];
    std::string consumers[10];

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < 10; i++, j++) {
        std::cout << "Please enter an amount of pancakes eaten by consumer"\
        " number " << j << "." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> pancakeAmount[i];
        std::cout << "Please enter the name of the person who ate that amount"\
        " of pancakes." << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, consumers[i]);
    }

    std::cout << "The results from least amount eaten to the greatest amount"\
    " eaten are as follows:" << std::endl;

    bubbleSort(pancakeAmount, 10);

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        std::cout << pancakeAmount[k] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That is the problem I am currently working on. As of right now, the first two objectives of this problem have been solved without any notable issues.

The third objective, however, is proving to be a bit more difficult. I am having a hard time designing/implementing a sorted list with the appropriate labels. In line 47 I am trying to obtain a name or label to give to the corresponding amount.

I am running into an issue where the console will accept the amount I want to assign, but will completely ignore the call to the getline() function and loop back into asking for another amount. When the getline() function is called before the "std::cin >> pancakeAmount[i]" is called, I can give input on the first loop, but successive loops produce the error I was encountering when the getline() function was in it's original position in the code.

Am I trying to utilize an array of strings in an improper fashion, or is the getline() function not being used properly?

Comment: ★★★★★ Add new lines to your "real" question, don't give orders and put some effort in your questions if you expect answers.

Comment: Why do you need to enter them on different lines? Would be easy enough to have "name #" be your input. As an alternative implementation you can store each "pancake record" as a class or struct. Then create an array of those types. As you traverse your list you can move the entire record (moving a pointer would be more efficient, but with such a small set size you can get by with a full copy) in your sort algo. Once it's sorted, walk the list for the full implementation and take the record at the end for the least number of pancakes.

Answer (score 0):

So today is your lucky day, because usually I don't do homework.
Your problem is that you need to ignore the return of your cin.

So this should solve your problem but it is not tested:

```
struct PanCakeEater
{
    int pancakeEaten;
    std::string name;
};
bool PanCakeSort(PanCakeEater const& eater1, PanCakeEater const& eater2)
{
    return eater1.pancakeEaten < eater2.pancakeEaten;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<PanCakeEater> eaters;
    const size_t numberOfEaters = 3;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numberOfEaters; ++i)
    {
        PanCakeEater p;
        std::cout << "Please enter an amount of pancakes eaten by consumer number " << i << "." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> p.pancakeEaten;
        std::cin.ignore(); // ignore the \n
        std::cout << "Please enter the name of the person who ate that amount of pancakes." << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, p.name);
        eaters.push_back(p);
    }
    std::sort(eaters.begin(), eaters.end(), PanCakeSort);
    for(auto iter = eaters.begin(); iter != eaters.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->name << ": " << iter->pancakeEaten << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for giving the solution while knowing that it's a homework

Comment: @Jaywalker: I don't see where I gave the solution. Mine is smarter but the basic problems are solved by the OP. And the missing ignore on the cin is quite a common problem, I have seen very often.

Comment: I should have probably added that this is not homework. This was an exercise found on the cplusplus.com forums. There was a post that had exercises meant to scale along with the layout of the tutorial on that site.

Comment: @Mr.Zero: Actually I don't care if it was homework or not. The mistake was the missing `std::cin.ignore()`, so I hope my positng helped you. But anyway you should take a closer look at the STL there are some more thing that can be improved in my program but I will leave this up to you.

Comment: I thank you for that. You did answer my question and even though it was a simple correction (aside from the improvements you made in your code) it was something I did not know and have now learned.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()

    {

     int ate[10],eater[10],hold,temp;

     cout<<"\t\tEnter How Many Pancakes Did Each Person Eat?\n\n";

     for(int h=0;h<10;h++)

     {

      eater[h]=h;

     }

     for(int q=0;q<10;q++)

     {

      cout<<"Person "<<eater[q]+1<<" Ate: ";

      cin>>ate[q];

     }

     cout<<"____________________________________________\n\n"<<"\t\tOrdered  List Of Above.\n\n";

     for(int a=0;a<10;a++)

 {

  for(int b=0;b<10;b++)

  {

   if(ate[b]<ate[b+1])

   {

    hold=ate[b];

    ate[b]=ate[b+1];

    ate[b+1]=hold;

    temp=eater[b];

    eater[b]=eater[b+1];

    eater[b+1]=temp;

   }

  }

 }

 for(int w=0;w<10;w++)

 {

  cout<<"Person "<<eater[w]+1<<" Ate "<<ate[w]<<" Pancakes\n";

 }

 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version of it. Must be easier for some beginners to understand.

```
#include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;
  int main() {
      int y;
      cout << "How many people do you want to enter=  \n";
      cin >> y;
      string names[10];
      int pancakes[10];

      for (int i = 0; i <= y-1 ; i++) {
          cout << "enter name= ";
          cin >> names[i];
          cout << "num of pancakes= ";
          cin >> pancakes[i];
      }
      int maxEaten = pancakes[0];
      int minEaten = pancakes[0];
      string maxPer = names[0];
      string minPer = names[0];

      for (int k = 1; k < y; k++) {
          if (pancakes[0] < pancakes[k]) {
              maxEaten = pancakes[k];
              maxPer = names[k];
          }
          if (pancakes[0] > pancakes[k]) {
              minEaten = pancakes[k];
              minPer = names[k];
          }
      }


      cout << maxPer << " ate " << maxEaten << " which is the maximum." << endl;
      cout << minPer << " ate " << minEaten << " which is the minimum." << endl;

      system("pause");
}
```